# How do you unit test methods with hard/impossible inputs to hardcode?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have the following problem. I have a method which takes two other custom objects to work. This objects are required by the method because they have the information that the method requires to perform its operations. Normally, you could mock the objects and just hardcode the API of this objects.

The problem here is that the methods that this objects return is hard/impossible to replicate by hardcoding because it includes images and arrays with several parameters. This complicated data is used by the other object to perform some calculations, and this method is suposed to format the output and make some graphical analysis with the output data.

I have checked [Should each unit test be able to be run independently of other tests?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/64306/386805) on how to do this, looking for a way of testing this method which doesn't include to construct the two objects needed inside the test but I have found nothing that solves this problem.

My question is: Should I just use my objects constructors to test this method or there's another cleaner way to test this method?

Pd: I'm working in python, but I hope to find a language-independent solution

Comment: Can you use the existing data to stub the methods for testing?

Comment: Sounds to me like you might have a level of detail issue. Either what you are looking for are module level tests, in which case sure load them up as real classes and pass them in, and then check the output. Or you really should break this class into smaller pieces so that you can independently verify orchestration logic, and the various transforms in simpler terms. You can still leave the class itself around as a facade/orchestrator, but it should be much easier to unit test.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I could, but for generating the data I would have to use the previous objects or, instead, do a sizeable work comparable to implement the objects again (Because that it their function) . Plus, if the requirements change for some reason, I would have to update the data and the objects separately.

Comment: I am pretty sure this question is unanswerable from this 30000 feet view presented in this question. One has to look at the real code (codereview.stackexchange.com is the place for this).

Comment: @Kain0_0 I don't really understand what you are talking about. Can you point me towards an example?

Comment: @DocBrown I feel like this must be a common enough problem to guarantee a general solution. I'm sure there's applications which use complicated data which has to be generated in some custom way and not easily hardcoded. But if I can't find a solution here I'll try my luck in that site.

Comment: What Kain is saying in broad brush strokes is that your class needs to be redesigned so that it is more easily testable, perhaps by breaking it into several smaller classes.

Comment: @JorgeVerdeguerGómez: their is no "general solution". One needs to know what *"includes images and arrays with several parameters"* exactly means, where these other "two objects" are coming from, how their API looks like, how likely it is they change their behaviour, on what kind of changes you unit test must fail or not fail, what the method to be tested does exactly with the input and output, how likely  changes will occur there, what the goal of the test should be, if it is possible to construct a simplified kind of image, and so on...

Comment: If you require a large data set for a test then by all means load it from the hard drive. Just be sure to separate this slow test from the faster hard coded tests so it wont slow them down. Nothing mentioned here is impossible to test.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The module that loads the data is already tested, and is internally split in really simple units. Since a third party library needs all the data processed by my first object, doesn't make sense to split it any further, unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: Are the "really simple units" already covered by unit tests?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes they are.

Comment: So ... What we're really talking about here are *integration tests,* not unit tests.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know that I could use this objects to make an integration test, but I want to know how would I unit test this method.

Comment: Well, if you've already broken this class into separate components that are fully tested, all that's left is to test the *integration* between components, and that can be easily done with the data you already have.

Answer (score 2):

### SRP

> The problem here is that the methods that this objects return is hard/impossible to replicate by hardcoding because it includes images and arrays with several parameters. This complicated data is used by the other object to perform some calculations, and this method is suposed to format the output and make some graphical analysis with the output data.

This sounds like a lot of work/responsibility for something that you call a "unit". For example, it makes no sense for both image processing and graph outputting to be tested as a single unit. Those are two completely independent behaviors.

I support RobertHarvey and Kain's suggestion of breaking this down in smaller chunks. It's going to dramatically improve your testability and reduce the complexity of your inputs and outputs.

### Unit testing with large input data

Let's assume you've broken down your logic, and you're trying to unit test the image processing logic. For the sake of example, let's say the logic counts how many pixels of each color there are in the image.
This is an appropriate unit test, but the image is still a non-trivial data set to construct out of nowhere. So how do you define this test data?

> The problem here is that the methods that this objects return is hard/impossible to replicate by hardcoding because it includes images and arrays with several parameters.

Unit tests don't limit you to having to hardcode inputs in the test method itself. What is important is that the values of the input data are considered a fixed given, i.e. the test presumes a specific input. For simple data, that's trivially done by hardcoding it, but that's not feasible for larger data sets.

> looking for a way of testing this method which doesn't include to construct the two objects needed inside the test

The simple solution here is to include an **actual image** in your test project, and simply read that image's file content. If I know that `myImage.jpg` contains 110 black pixels and 890 white pixels, I can write a unit test that asserts these values are the output of the image processing logic.

Just like how you decide an arbitrary value when hardcoding something, you can use an arbitrarily decided image file.

It doesn't *have* to be a literal image file. It could also be a hardcoded string that you keep in a separate file, e.g. a `TestImages` class with static string properties containing the base64 file content.

I would try to work with image files where possible, simply because it's easier for a test writer to understand which image they're using in their test. The minor performance hit from reading the file is negligible since unit tests aren't written to be performant to begin with.

*Note: The same answer/principle applies to any unwieldy large data sets, not just images. Simply define them elsewhere and refer to them in your unit test. For example, in a unit test for an import script that had to process a massive XML file, we simply had a collection of XML files with particular representative data cases which we used.*

Comment: Actually I'm using a small dataset to test other parts of the codebase. The problem is that the dataset by itself is not enough, it has to be processed because it has to be normalized and filters applied (Like removing NAN values and so).

Comment: @JorgeVerdeguerGómez: There's no need to test all those things at once. If you write a test that confirms NAN values are filtered, then your other test can work with a data set that doesn't contain any NAN values. Same goes for normalization. This is why people are suggesting you break down your logic (and thus tests) into more easily digestible chunks. You're trying to take too much on all at once, which is contributing to the complexity that is now your roadblock.

Comment: As I said, I have tests that are already testing that. The two objects that I'm passing to this method are already tested. It is not responsability of this method to check if the data is correct. However, it is its responsability to be able to operate on clean data, because it is what it will receive from the other object.

Comment: @JorgeVerdeguerGómez, If you are confident that those input objects are correct (and if they aren't, a test related to them will show that), then by all means use those objects in your test.

Comment: @JorgeVerdeguerGómez That the data gets cleaned vs what you do with the clean data afterwards are two separate responsibilities, which should be tested separately. The latter test can be provided clean data without needing to sanitize it any further. Unit tests focus on the specific unit. The unit that uses the clean data therefore should be supplied with clean data in its test.

Answer (score 0):

"Should I just use my objects constructors to test this method or there's another cleaner way to test this method?"

Yes to both.

Yes. It sounds like you have a complex case and simply using your existing objects to test the third is pragmatic. You can argue about whether its a unit or integration test later.

Yes. The cleaner way would be to mock the parameter objects with some classes which have the same interface but are populated by some static data.

In order to achieve this second cleaner method I would suggest

1. Make sure you are passing interfaces rather than concrete objects
2. Make a serialiser for your objects that can write them or the results of any method calls to a file.
3. Make a simple object with no logic which matches the same interface
4. Populate it from a file created by the serialiser of a real object.

Obviously this is more work. But its good work. If you find that you can't do it due to some complexity of your objects then it suggests that there may be a problem with your overall design.

Mostly when people object to these "best practice" style answers it's not because it's impossible, it's because it questions their design decisions. Sometimes its because they have an exceptional case. But if you have an exceptional case there's no way for us to know unless you post all your code and the answer will be specific to your case.